# Jitterbit - Move multiple files from one location to another

Tags: jitterbit

1. I have source as local file and target as File share.
2. I want to move all files from local file folder to file share folder.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say local, are you referring to local to your private agent server?  If so, you could do run FileList(), then ReadFile().  Then just write the files back to your target location as an FTP (or, just to a shared folder on the Jitterbit server).  If I'm off on what you are trying to do, please let me know. Happy to help out.

```
<trans>
  $sourceFileNames=FileList("<TAG>Sources/Read_All_Test_Files</TAG>"); 
  $numberofFiles=Length($sourceFileNames); 
  While($numberofFiles>0, 
    $fname=$sourceFileNames[$numberofFiles-1]; 
    WriteFile("<TAG>Targets/Move_Test_Files</TAG>",ReadFile("<TAG>Sources/Move_Test_Files</TAG>",$fname),$fname);
    $numberofFiles--;
  ); 
</trans>
```

Comment: I have used following script

Comment: I have used following script
<trans>
$sourceFileNames=FileList("<TAG>Sources/INV_ARC_MOVE_Source</TAG>");
$numberofFiles=Length(FileList("<TAG>Sources/INV_ARC_MOVE_Source</TAG>"));
While($numberofFiles>0,
WriteFile("<TAG>Targets/INV_ARC_MOVE_Target</TAG>",
ReadFile("<TAG>Sources/INV_ARC_MOVE_Source</TAG>",$sourceFileNames[$numberofFiles-1]),
$fname=$sourceFileNames[$numberofFiles-1]);$numberofFiles-1);
</trans>

In source, file name is * (all files)
In target, file name is $fname

When I have run, its continue running, not getting anything output.

Comment: Here you go.  I made a couple of minor alterations.  This one works fine with my SFTP servers.  One specific item I notices is that you used $numberofFiles-1;.  That doesn't work.  It should be $numberofFiles--;.  Next comment holds the script.

Comment: <trans>
$sourceFileNames=FileList("<TAG>Sources/Read_All_Test_Files</TAG>");
$numberofFiles=Length($sourceFileNames);
While($numberofFiles>0,
  $fname=$sourceFileNames[$numberofFiles-1];
  WriteFile("<TAG>Targets/Move_Test_Files</TAG>",ReadFile("<TAG>Sources/Move_Test_Files</TAG>",$fname),$fname);
  $numberofFiles--;
);
</trans>

Comment: Sounds great.  Can you mark this as the answer?  I'll update my answer with the script.